# Unable to display "&" on my button.text

Tags: vb.net

I am unable to change my button text to "&" .

```
Button1.text = "&"
```

When I run the program button has no text.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "&" character is used to indicate short-cut keys.

To display the & itself, use it two times  ("&&").

Comment: Did you put && in the button.text? What happened?

Comment: Try adding some spaces to the end. Perhaps a 1 character name is not allowed.

Comment: @a-z : Button1.Text = "&&" should work ! Try clean and rebuild the application .

Comment: Then your single program statement won't be of any help. Post your entire code. BTW, are you looking on the right button where "&" should be displayed ?

Comment: Okay,Found the error, the  button width was too short, it was suppose to display only one character. I guess when you use "&&", first VS puts a space then prints &

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `&` is used to make a keyboard Alt shortcut (eg. "&a" would make an Alt+a shortcut for that button), so you need to use two ampersands `&&` and it should work.

Comment: @abcd Not working in which way? Did you remember to recompile?

Comment: @It works on a new form , maybe I did something wrong in my app

Comment: Are you setting it to && before you call InitializeComponent?  Because odds are you set it on the Form properties as well and that would get set during InitializeComponent.